# Flex Spark List item render with delayed refresh

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex-spark

I have a spark List in which I am adding custom components manually (without an item renderer). Everything is working fine except when I add hundreds of items in the list (based on several calculations), the render time increases to several seconds.

My questions are:

1. Does flex automatically delay the rendition of components that are added to a list?
2. If not then, how can I tell the spark list to only render the components once everything is added.

I hope what I am asking makes sense. I am pretty sure the render time is increasing because I have quite a few components inside the custom component. I just need a simple answer to my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more thing to know is that,

ActionScript 3 runs on flash player based on even-driven. It means that if you run a chunk of code in blocking, anything else, including rendering, will not be executed until the code ends.

This design sometimes causes issues: If a developer adds too much job in one blocking function, the player looks frozen and unresponsive momentarily. (If the code is an infinite loop, it stops until the player detects and throws ScriptTimeoutError, or possibly forever.)

However, for your question, yes, anything will be delayed until the adding job is done. Flex components doesn't basically split the job automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Flex components are rendered in the list according to the Flex lifecycle: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7fff.html

There are two reasons your List may be running slow, your components may not be following the Flex lifecycle correctly and the second because virtual layouts are not enabled on your List.

First the hard one:

Your first step should be to ensure you are following the correct phases in your custom components for `commitProperties()`, `measure()` and `updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number)`.

So long as you are not calling any method named `validateNow()` on either your UIComponent subclasses or the LayoutManager then your components should follow this just fine.

The second may be that your list layout is not using virtual layout. This is enabled by default in a Spark List component but if you're overriding the layout you should ensure that `useVirtualLayout` is set to true on whatever layout you're using.

This is the property to enable it:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html#useVirtualLayout

This is what it does to speed up rendering many items in a Spark DataGroup component (which a List is):
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc2368ca491e3ff92-1483ec4a12136246e76-8000.html#WS685c4ccbb85d340c6617851e121d4b8abae-8000